# What is the preferable way of initializing default arguments of a constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, default-parameters

I have seen following two ways of default initializing the arguments in constructors(which is also applicable in normal free functions too).

```
#include <string>
using UserDefinedType = std::string;

class MyClass
{
    UserDefinedType m_member;
public:
    // Way - 1
    MyClass(const UserDefinedType &obj = UserDefinedType()) : m_member{ obj } {}
    // Way - 2
    //MyClass(const UserDefinedType &obj = {}) : m_member{ obj }  {}
};
```

- I know the first will defensively(explicitly) call the constructor
     of user defined type. What **happens in the second** way?
- Which is **the preferable way** of practicing with modern compilers(C++11
  or later) ?

Comment: Second way won't work for `explicit` default constructor.

Comment: @Jarod42 Are you sure?? The second one will compile with the above mentioned key word: https://ideone.com/QEvAp3

Comment: I meant if `UserDefinedType`'s default constructor is `explicit` [Demo](https://ideone.com/Z7iZou)

Comment: But explicit default constructor is pathological case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a matter of personal preference, there are no implications on what these two options do or invoke. As I guess it is common sense to not repeatedly type types as in

```
const int three = static_cast<int>(3.14);
const Sub* sub = dynamic_cast<Sub*>(&baseInstance);
```

which is often written down with `auto` as

```
// better, the concrete type is only typed once, less maintainance "burden":
const auto three = static_cast<int>(3.14);
const auto* sub = dynamic_cast<Sub*>(&baseInstance);
```

you could take this argument and transfer it to the example snippet above:

```
MyClass(const UserDefinedType &obj = UserDefinedType());
```

Here, the type is spelled out twice, and that's undesirable. Hence, I recommend going with

```
// Shorter, not less readable - a default-constructed default instance:
MyClass(const UserDefinedType &obj = {})
```

Note that in the special case of constructors, it is equally simple to use in-class member initialization together with a default constructor and an additional overload, e.g.

```
MyClass {
  public:
    MyClass() = default;
    explicit MyClass(const UserDefinedType& obj) : m_member{obj} {}

  private:
    UserDefinedType m_member = {};
};
```

The advantage of this approach is the low likelihood of introducing bugs when a new constructor overload is added to the class. But this is a nuance. Note, however, that I've marked the single-argument ctor `explicit`, which is usually considered good practice to prevent accidental implicit conversions.

Comment: Hi.. thanks for your answer. could you tell me **What happens in the second way?**, what does it call and will it also call the constructor of `UserDefinedType`?

Comment: and  your suggested(last code) is only applicable when for all constructors(not only the given case) the `UserDefinedType m_member = {};` should be **true** or **okay to have**.

Comment: @Using That's correct, but I think the situation where a default ctor parameter is bound to one specific ctor overload and is not invariant to the chosen ctor is rather rare.

Comment: And for the first comment: the first and the second syntax are identical in terms of what happens. The curly braces are just another syntactic way to initialize an instance.